# How to achieve state persistence even after a reload in Ngrx

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ngrx

I have a shopping cart which I am maintaining with Ngrx and for maintaining the persistence of the state after a page refresh I have two options:

1. Stringify the state and store it in local storage and get it back after the reload.
2. Stringify the state and store it inside a text file and then get the string out of the file and use JSON.parse to convert the string back to a JSON object.

I am storing some price related data so didn't want to store in local storage.

What should I use? Or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ngrx-store-localstorage package as https://stackoverflow.com/a/58362198/10112124 mentioned, or write your custom meta-reducer or as you mentioned use effects to do this. For the latter, Tomas Trajan has an example in his [angular-ngrx-material-starter](https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-ngrx-material-starter/blob/master/projects/angular-ngrx-material-starter/src/app/core/settings/settings.effects.ts#L65) project.

All the above options are find, but I wanted to give an answer on what to store

> I am storing some price related data so didn't want to store in local storage.

If you have sensitive information, you could store it in the sessions storage - when the session is ended, the storage will be cleaned up.

You shouldn't have to store sensitive information, why don't you store important information like the article id and the quantity? This way you can rehydrate the store with this information, and build up your shopping cart with this information plus the products of the catalog you would load in a normal way.

Answer (score 2):

Using the following library you can achieve your desired result

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-store-localstorage

I am using it myself in multiple projects and it works great, it acts as a meta reducer and therefore 'automatically' takes care of things for you.

https://ngrx.io/guide/store/metareducers

Comment: I was thinking about using simple local storage inside ngrx effects and using a service to access it. What benefits does the mentioned library provide over simply using localstorage.setItem("state",state);

Comment: It offers quite a few things such as automatically rehydrating your state on reload of your page as an example. It can also persist only parts of your state into the storage and a bunch more options, please check the npm site for all options. Reinventing the wheel is generally not the best idea, but adding a lot of libraries to your project can also make it heavier than needed, I can only report very good experiences with ngrx-store-localstorage though.